# Python Iterator - For i in [something]

Tags: python

In the Following code:

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self):
        self.volume = []
        self.index = -1

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.volume.append(item)


    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # self.index +=1     NOTE - It is commented 
        if self.index >= len(self.volume):
            raise StopIteration
        return self.volume[self.index]

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight 

b = Box()
b.add_item(Item('Cat', 5))
b.add_item(Item('Nintendo Switch', 1))
b.add_item(Item('Potatoes', 2))

for item in b:
    print('The {} weighs {} kg'.format(item.name.lower(), item.weight))
```

so we make an object 'b' of type Box and add three items to it.

Question 1) - **What does for items in b mean? what is it referring to? what is in b?**

Question 2) - **Assuming it refers to the the three items we added to it. Why does it go on infine loop stuck on:
    The potato weighs 2 kg
and Not going to the other 2 elements?**  (It works fine if I increment )

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused why you have to ask what `for items in b` means. Did you implement `__iter__` and `__next__` without having a clue what they do...?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I am student and I may not have complete knowledge about it but i know what it does. It gets the next item. I am confused because how does 'python' know what is in the box. shouldn't it be for  i in b. volume as the items are added there? that's what i wanted to ask, what is in b to iterate over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1) - What does for items in b mean? what is it referring to? what is in b?

This is documented:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

> Question 2) - Assuming it refers to the the three items we added to it. Why does it go on infine loop stuck on: The potato weighs 2 kg and Not going to the other 2 elements? (It works fine if I increment )

Because if you don't increment the index, it's never greater than `len(self.volume)`, so your iterator always yields the same object and never raises `StopIteration`.

EDIT

> shouldn't it be 'for i in b.volume' as we added items in volume variable not in 'b'?

Well, the point of making `Box` an iterable (and an iterator) is actually to hide how `Item`s are stored ([law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter))- note how the client code uses `Box.add_item()`, not `Box.volume.append()`.

The current implementation is faulty though as it exposes `.volume` and `index` as part of the public API when they should be protected (names prefixed with a single leading underscore, which is the Python convention for "protected" attributes), and it's possibly a bit incomplete too (it should at least expose a way to know if the box is empty / how many items it contains).

Comment: shouldn't it be 'for i in b.volume' as we added items in volume variable not in 'b'?