# My understanding of this class with iterators and generators - please correct me if I am wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I recently posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117789/python-iterator-for-i-in-something), and with the help of some of you and also my reading, I came to the the understanding that:

From my original question I had posted was - what is the meaning of `for item in b`. Although I knew how `for i in something` works, I didn't understand why we are using `b` as we put items (see code below) in `b.volume` not in `b`. How would python know what is in `b` if we never put stuff in it (but in `b.volume` instead).

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self):
        self.volume = []
        self.index = -1

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.volume.append(item)


    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.index +=1  
        if self.index >= len(self.volume):
            raise StopIteration
        return self.volume[self.index]

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight 

b = Box()
b.add_item(Item('Cat', 5))
b.add_item(Item('Nintendo Switch', 1))
b.add_item(Item('Potatoes', 2))

for i in b:
    print('The {} weighs {} kg'.format(item.name.lower(), item.weight))
```

So instead of `for i in b`, I thought it should have been `for i in b.volume`.

Here is what I think is right:

1. I think when we call `for i in b` it calls `__iter__` and `__next__` method for the `object b`. It tell that go to the `__iter__` and `__next__` of `b` (like just to specify the object so it doesn't go to some other object's `__iter__` method if  defined)

   So after `for i in b`, `__iter__` method of the object `b`,  is called and then the `__next__` method. The `__next__` method returns something, which happens to be the value of `i (for i in b)`.

   Also, Python here doesn't know how many iterations it will perform as there is no list generated for `eq` For `i in range(5)` generates a list of [0,1,2,3,4] to b iterated over.

   It is done until stop iteration is raised.
2. doing for `i in b.volume` will work, but then would defeat the purpose of `__iter__` and `__next__`.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the stuff your think is with the code is right, but also just telling you that, this works with `b.volume` will also work, so:

```
for i in b.volume:
    print('The {} weighs {} kg'.format(i.name.lower(), i.weight))
```

Also gives:

```
The cat weighs 5 kg
The nintendo switch weighs 1 kg
The potatoes weighs 2 kg
```

Note: (as in my example), `item` should be `i` in this case (in the last loop).

Comment: @lynxx Happy to help, :-), , since you've got 15 reputation, you can upvote :-), if you want:-)

Comment: Upvoted thanks. :) :) :) Also, Yes `b.volume` would work but that would defeat the purpose of iterator (with b.volume, iterator is not required), isn't it?

Comment: @lynxx Yup, then no need `__next__` and `__iter__`.